# How to block mysql EXTRACTVALUE with fail2ban?

Tags: fail2ban

How to block these with fail2ban?

```
45.154.255.147 - - [25/May/2021:08:32:40 -0700] "GET /search.php?q=xgp%2F%2A%2A%2Fbangla%2F%2A%2A%2Fcom%27%20PROCEDURE%20ANALYSE%28EXTRACTVALUE%281915%2CCONCAT%280x5c%2C0x71707a6271%2C%28SELECT%20%28CASE%20WHEN%20%281915%3D1915%29%20THEN%201%20ELSE%200%20END%29%29%2C0x7176767071%29%29%2C1%29%20AND%20%27uOyt%27%3D%27uOyt HTTP/1.1" 200 11884 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:2.0b11pre) Gecko/20110129 Firefox/4.0b11pre"
46.232.249.138 - - [25/May/2021:08:36:28 -0700] "GET /search.php?q=xgp%2F%2A%2A%2Fbangla%2F%2A%2A%2Fcom%27%29%20PROCEDURE%20ANALYSE%28EXTRACTVALUE%281915%2CCONCAT%280x5c%2C0x71707a6271%2C%28SELECT%20%28CASE%20WHEN%20%281915%3D1915%29%20THEN%201%20ELSE%200%20END%29%29%2C0x7176767071%29%29%2C1%29%20AND%20%28%27BInS%27%20LIKE%20%27BInS HTTP/1.1" 200 10092 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:2.0b11pre) Gecko/20110129 Firefox/4.0b11pre"
45.129.56.200 - - [25/May/2021:08:36:37 -0700] "GET /search.php?q=xgp%2F%2A%2A%2Fbangla%2F%2A%2A%2Fcom%27%20PROCEDURE%20ANALYSE%28EXTRACTVALUE%281915%2CCONCAT%280x5c%2C0x71707a6271%2C%28SELECT%20%28CASE%20WHEN%20%281915%3D1915%29%20THEN%201%20ELSE%200%20END%29%29%2C0x7176767071%29%29%2C1%29%20AND%20%27htVh%27%20LIKE%20%27htVh HTTP/1.1" 200 11910 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:2.0b11pre) Gecko/20110129 Firefox/4.0b11pre"
23.129.64.232 - - [25/May/2021:08:36:39 -0700] "GET /search.php?q=xgp%2F%2A%2A%2Fbangla%2F%2A%2A%2Fcom%22%29%20PROCEDURE%20ANALYSE%28EXTRACTVALUE%281915%2CCONCAT%280x5c%2C0x71707a6271%2C%28SELECT%20%28CASE%20WHEN%20%281915%3D1915%29%20THEN%201%20ELSE%200%20END%29%29%2C0x7176767071%29%29%2C1%29%20AND%20%28%22CSNy%22%3D%22CSNy HTTP/1.1" 200 10054 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:2.0b11pre) Gecko/20110129 Firefox/4.0b11pre"
23.129.64.232 - - [25/May/2021:08:36:45 -0700] "GET /search.php?q=xgp%2F%2A%2A%2Fbangla%2F%2A%2A%2Fcom%22%20PROCEDURE%20ANALYSE%28EXTRACTVALUE%281915%2CCONCAT%280x5c%2C0x71707a6271%2C%28SELECT%20%28CASE%20WHEN%20%281915%3D1915%29%20THEN%201%20ELSE%200%20END%29%29%2C0x7176767071%29%29%2C1%29%20AND%20%22NYRo%22%3D%22NYRo HTTP/1.1" 200 10043 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:2.0b11pre) Gecko/20110129 Firefox/4.0b11pre"
```

Founded with this:

```
sudo grep "EXTRACTVALUE"  /var/log/httpd/access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the regex may be something like this:

```regex
^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ \[\] "GET /search\.php\?[^"]*EXTRACTVALUE[^"]*"
```

But it is not advisable to do something like this:

- service seems to response with 200 now, so it looks like valid request for that (no parameter validation?);
- it may affect legitimate users (accidentally sending in query some "evil" word);
- it can be simple for intruder to avoid the ban, by changing sql statement (switch to other functions, split EXTRACTVALUE in two words, switch to POST http-method containing `q` argument, which is not logged, etc);
- correct prevention against SQL injections makes such "attacks" senseless and useless

If really needed, better would be to prevent such "attack" on service side (e. g. in `search.php` or in API it is using) and do response with 50x code on such URL parameters by its validation.
Then a fail2ban filter checking 50x code could ban it also.

Comment: search.php adopts its own countermeasures and similar attacks fail to do any damage, but if you try to attack me, I would like to kick you off my server for good.